# Calling a function through its address in memory in c / c++

Tags: c++, c, function-call, memory-address

Given knowledge of the prototype of a function and its address in memory, is it possible to call this function from another process or some piece of code that knows nothing but the prototype and memory address? If possible, how can a returned type be handled back in the code?

Comment: In C++ there are no processes. You need to specify your platform if you want help with that.

Comment: From another process? That's a very special case. Do you really need that?

Comment: So it is possible from another thread of the same executable but not in between executable? What if it is a shared library?

Comment: @jalf the idea is to create sort of a HANDLE to manipulate internals of other processes.

Comment: @ddriver - it sounds like you want to investigate inter-process communication, not function pointers.  Unless you're trying to write a debugger, in which case you have a lot of hurdles ahead of you.

Comment: @ddriver If you're talking about calling from a different process, you really do need to specify the platform. In most modern operating systems the memory owned by one process can't be arbitrarily read or written by a different process. If two processes want to share a region of memory, they have to set that up explicitly. This is generally a good thing, as it prevents a bad pointer or other bug in one process from taking down other processes, or even the entire OS.

Comment: @Caleb: what problem are you trying to solve? In general, there are a lot of limitations on how processes can interact, and calling raw functions from other processes is very very tricky to do safely and reliably. Try to take a step back and explain to us what the end goal is, because it sounds like right now you're heading down the wrong track

Answer (score 60, accepted):

On modern operating systems, each ***process has its own address space*** and addresses are only valid within a process. If you want to execute code in some other process, you either have to ***inject a shared library*** or ***attach your program as a debugger***.

Once you are in the other program's address space, this code ***invokes a function at an arbitrary address***:

```
typedef int func(void);
func* f = (func*)0xdeadbeef;
int i = f();
```

Comment: Thanks to @R.Martinho for the [better style to typedef function prototypes](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2400130#2400130). I hadn't even known this works!

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to *write* memory in other programs address space in new operating systems and that causes a SEGFAULT. But there's nothing that prevents a program from reading any memory location (hence, the heartbleed bug being scary in OpenSSL, because you can read anything in memory with that). So, Could you explain why I can't access other program's address space and require shared libraries or debugger?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Because each process has its own virtual memory space. Your process' `0xdeadbeef` is yours, and my process' is mine. They are located at different addresses of physical memory.

Comment: @abi  Only if the computer has an MMU.  The computer might not even have processes if there is no OS...

Answer (score 14):

Yes - you're describing a function pointer.  Here's a simple example;

```
int (*func)(void) = (int (*)(void))0x12345678;
int x = func();
```

It probably won't work between processes - in most operating systems, processes don't have access to each other's memory.

Comment: Why casting to void (*)(void) to assign a int(*)(void) ? That's quite illogical no?

Answer (score 8):

When you need a direct call:

```
((void(*)(void))0x1234)();
```

Answer (score 7):

All previous answers are nice but much too long:

```c
int i = ((int (*)(void))0xdeadbeef)();
//                      ==========     --> addr of the function to call
//        =============                --> type of the function to call
//       =========================     --> ... we get a ptr to that fct
//      =============================  --> ... and we call the function
```

Comment: No, they were great. Yours on the other hand is very poor. No explanatiom at all.

Answer (score 1):

In most OP, every process has its own memory, so you can't.

Sample code:
a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int r() {return 2;}
int main() {
    printf("%p\n",r);
    while(1);
}
```

b.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int a,(*b)();
scanf("%p",&b);
a=b();
printf("%d\n",a);
return 0;
}
```

this get segmentation fault.

Comment: In c c++ you can access any memory location you want, for better or worse

Comment: @ddriver: C++ allows you to access any _virtual_ memory location.  However, many OS's give each process it's own virtual memory, so they can't affect each other.  There are OS-specific calls you can make/use to affect another processes memory though.

Comment: @ddriver - no you can't.  You can only access memory locations the operating system lets you access.  All your program knows is the virtual memory environment in which it's running, which normally bears pretty much no relationship to physical reality.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible, but there are restrictions. Each process will have its own block of memory which other processes can't interfere with. Now, you will notice, I wrote it is definitely possible, this is through DLL injection (or code injection).

We can use the typedef keyword to achieve this. Now, I see you've marked the answer as 'Answered' and it seems you've gotten on fine, this is just a notice for anyone else that may be interested.

Comment: That depends on your OS - if you have one.  Some computers don't have a hardware MMU so there are no memory barriers - so even if there is an OS, the processes CAN write to each other's memory.