# Call a function in C++ by its address without knowing the return type

Tags: c++, c, memory-address, function-call

I want to call a C function from a C++ dll by its address.

I know how to do it where the return type is known from this separate question: [Calling a function through its address in memory in c / c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915797/calling-a-function-through-its-address-in-memory-in-c-c).

However, if I do not know the return type, what can I do? I've tried "typedef auto", but it seems you cannot use auto like that.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you don't know the return type? The way the function must be called (the calling convention) depends on its return type.

Comment: The bad news is, if you don't know the return type at compile time, this is *impossible* without a chunk of hand-written assembly language.  The good news is, someone has already hand-written the assembly language for you: [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).

Comment: Do you know the return type at run-time?

Comment: Yes, I do know what the return type is at run-time. It's a PyObject*

Comment: ... If you can say "It's a PyObject*", then you _do_ know the type at compile time, don't you?

Comment: Knew someone would say that. I used the wording of not knowing the return type because I can't use PyObject* in my typedef. In hindsight, the original question is a bit of an XY problem.

Comment: Why can't you use `PyObject*` in your typedef? What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What about a forward declaration? `struct PyObject;` and you can use it as your return type.

Comment: if it's a pointer, you could also simply use `void*` in your typedef

Comment: If you want to disregard return type, just declare return type as void. If you want to process the result, you must know its type.  After all, C is not Java or C# where type can be obtained at run time.

Comment: cyanide, that sounds like the perfect solution. If you make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the returning type is really unknown or it doesn't matter, you can use `void` in your function definition, or if it is any pointer you can use `void *`, but if the function is in a C coded DLL, and you'll use it in a C++ code, then you can utilize and share almost every type defined in your C code, because C++ it's a superset of C.

That said, I prepared a small example with a structure called `PyObject` shared in C and C++ codes.

To do this, is better creating a header with the shared types/definitions:

```
#ifndef PYOBJECT_DLL_H
#define PYOBJECT_DLL_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Common structure definition
typedef struct PyObject{
    int field1;
    char *field2;
} PyObject;

// Public function pointer type declaration
typedef PyObject *(*__stdcall getPyObject_t)(int arg1, const char *arg2);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // PYOBJECT_DLL_H
```

---

Let's suppose that the C code with the exported function is something like:

```
#include "pyobject.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
#endif
__declspec(dllexport) PyObject * getPyObject(int arg1, char *arg2);

PyObject *getPyObject(int arg1, char *arg2){
    PyObject *obj = (PyObject *)malloc(sizeof(PyObject));
    obj->field1 = arg1;
    obj->field2 = arg2;
    return obj;
}
```

---

Finally the C++ code using the function and data created in the library would be:

```
#include "pyobject.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    HINSTANCE dll = LoadLibrary("pyobject.dll");
    if (dll == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open pyobject.dll. Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    getPyObject_t getPyObject = (getPyObject_t) GetProcAddress(dll, "getPyObject");
    if (getPyObject == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot locate 'getPyObject' function in dll. Error: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        FreeLibrary(dll);
        return 2;
    }

    PyObject *obj = getPyObject(3, "test");
    std::cout << "PyObject == { field1: " << obj->field1 << ", field2: \"" << obj->field2 << "\"}\n";

    FreeLibrary(dll);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

As [@raymondchen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) pointed in his comment, ignoring the return type when the C function returns a large aggregate (e.g. struct) it's not a good idea, because the C function expects that the caller already has had reserved stack space to store the returned aggregate, but if the caller treats the function as `void` or anything else, then compiler will not reserve that space, causing unpredictable effects (probably ending with Segmentation fault error).

To avoid it, it's always better to define the correct type in both C and C++ codes (or in the common header), especially when the C function returns an aggregate.

Comment: If the return type is a large aggregate, then the calling convention changes.